# print content of more than one file in a zip archive

Tags: linux, compression, zip, unzip

I have some `zip` files that are really large and I want to print them without extracting first. I am using `zcat` and `zless` to do that and then I redirect the output to a different application. When my `zip` file contains more than one text file I receive the following error:

```
zcat tweets.zip >a
gzip: tweets.zip has more than one entry--rest ignored
```

How can I do what I want with `zip` files that contain more than one text file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the `-p` option of unzip to pipe the output.  Multiple files are concatenated.  The `-c` option does the same thing, but includes the file name in front of each file.

Answer (score 31):

You can do this to output a file without extracting:

```
$ unzip -p <zip_file> <file_to_print>
```

For example:

```
$ unzip -p MyEar.ear META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

As cur4so mentioned you can also list all files using:

```
$ unzip -l <zip_file>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see a list of files in your zip archive use:

```
unzip -l tweets.zip
```

if you want to extract just some file:

```
unzip tweets.zip file-of-interest-as-it-is-pointed-in-the-archive
```

if you want something else, could you clarify your question?